# OpenCV Python and Histogram of Oriented Gradient

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, numpy, gradient

Is there any useful documentation for using the HOGDescriptor functionality in Python OpenCV? I have read the C++ documentation, but the Python version functions differently and I cannot figure it out just by tinkering.

Most specifically, I am seeking an OpenCV command in Python that takes an image and a pixel location as input (and possibly also some parameters about the size of a detection window) and then just returns a Python array that contains the HOG feature vector (i.e. a list or NumPy array, etc., where the jth element of the list is the jth histogram component from a histogram of oriented gradients).

My goal is to feed these histograms into the scikits.learn SVM pipelines (so I can avoid the OpenCV SVM training), but to do this I need the actual feature vectors themselves and not the sort of HOG processing chain pipelines stuff that OpenCV appears to use.

Any other Python implementations of HOG code would work too. I need something reasonably efficient though to compare with another code base that I am writing myself.

Comment: Note: a reasonable C++ executable that has easy-to-use command line arguments would work too and I could just wrap it into my Python stuff. If you know any projects with efficient HOG code, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a bit of [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28689-hog-descriptor-for-matlab/content/HOG.m) as inspiration, belonging to this [article](http://www.isr.uc.pt/~urbano/PDFs_PUB/Conferencias_Internacionais/2009/%5B113%5D2009ITSC09-129-FI.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I can probably translate this into Python myself. It might be harder porting it to other languages, though.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little late, but, for future reference, [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) has an implementation of [HOG](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.4/api/skimage.feature.html#hog). This is a single function that could extract the Histogram of Oriented Gradients for a given image.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/hogtrainingtuto/?_test=beta for some HOG python code and a bunch of C, cpp, java implementations. As for real documentations of python and opencv, I too am at a loss. But this should help you a bit

Comment: I don't see any Python code in the archive file that I downloaded from that link. The only HOG related thing is an executable called 'cvHogFeatureCal' but it has no documentation that I can find. The other things is that OpenCV generally implements classifiers as cascades, where the user inputs hard negative images and then true positives for training, and OpenCV automatically goes all the way to producing the classifiers. I specifically need to avoid that and just hijack the HOG feature vectors then do classifier training with different software (scikits.learn).

Answer (score 0):

The 'Poselets' implementation [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~lbourdev/poselets/) has a C implementation of HOG descriptors which, although written with matlab in mind, can be adapted to run with python using ctypes and numpy.

You can remove all the mex routines, and declare your input and output arrays as `float *` in the C function.

You do need to make sure that your numpy arrays are Fortran contiguous. This can be achieved by:

`image = image.copy(order='F', dtype = float32)`

Comment: I use Poselet stuff pretty regularly. Based on how undocumented and inscrutable their Java code was for their browser annotation tool, I'm inclined to just use the Matlab code in the top post. The Poselet idea is great, but the fact that (a) it's in Matlab and (b) they don't want to help fellow scientists by providing any support for their code, makes me far less inclined to use their stuff. It would probably be just as much work to translate the top Matlab routine from Maurits.

Comment: Fair enough, I've not experimented with their implementation much, I guess largely due to it's lack of documentation! But I have built something similar using their HOG routine as I've outlined above, and it works well. If speed is a priority, utilising their C routine may be a better solution than nested loops in python.